# Starting an activity into foreground from a service

Tags: android

Basically, I want to pop up a dialog into foreground from a background service (I know using notification would be more user-friendly, but my app really needs immediate response from user). I have my service working. Then I define an activity that contains the dialog using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`.

In the service code, I start the dialog activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PopUpDialogActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The dialog can pop up if I'm in my app. But if I'm not in my app, the dialog doesn't pop up in foreground (I have to enter my app to see it). How can I start it directly into user focus?

Comment: I don't seem to have any problems in starting a translucent Activity from a background service, even whilst that application is not the currently active task. Can you provide the code where you start the service as well? Is there a possibility that it shuts down when you leave the app?

Comment: In the main activity, I have a toggle button, so the code to start service is: if (togglebutton.isChecked()) {startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));}. In the service, the code snippet of starting the dialog activity is defined in onStartCommand.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is bound to an activity then it will die when you exit your activity or app.  Use onPause() and onResume() to unbind and bind to the service so that it doesn't get killed when you exit/return.